# typeerror: result of expression x [undefined] is not an object - only on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I have the following script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var hiddenDiv;

 $('.ms-standardheader').each(function () {
        hiddenDiv = $(this).parent().next().children().find("div[contenteditable='true']");
        hiddenDiv.parent().hide();  
    });

    $('#txtNewBox').val(hiddenDiv.text());
});
```

It works fine in IE, Safari on PC, Chrome and FireFox but with Safari on iPad I get:

```
TypeError: result of expression hiddenDiv [undefined] is not an object
```

How do I fix this for Safari/iPad?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function call to .children() seems redundant since find() will search the children.

Comment: True, thanks for the comment, it shouldn't be the issue though?

Comment: Question should be retagged. Currently it only has a jquery tag.

Comment: No, that's probably not the issue. You might want to debug a bit and see why hiddenDiv is undefined and what line is throwing the error. Can't tell just from that code sample.

Comment: it doesn't give me that error when I don't run it on the iPad so it's a bit hard to debug, was just checking if this is a common error on iPad's. The line is $('#txtNewBox').val(hiddenDiv.text());